# Oracle not connecting in one region while successful in another

Tags: asp.net, database, windows, oracle11g, oracleclient

## ORACLE not available Error in specific region alone.

```
FAILURE ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-ia64
```

I am connecting ORacle DB via my web app.

I am getting this when I connect to Oracle DB 11g via my web application .
While it is successful in Region A ,it fails in Region B and throws the above error.

Both the regions have Oracle 11g client installed.

I did search most of them suggests

- "Restart DB" -I dont have access and it is not the case with Region
  A.
- "Check Oracle_home & ORacle SID" - Are these variables belong to
  client side or DB server side.I could not find that info from those
  links.

Please suggest why it is failing in one region.? **

Comment: Without knowing any specifics about your setup. The error message means the database is not running. So if you can connect in one situation but not in another this suggest you are not connecting to the same database.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that I use same connection string in both the region.